# Is there a way to tell the browser to autofill a specific field in a <form> if there are two or more <inputs> with the same label? - HTML, JS, React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

Can the browser be able to autofill a specific field in a  if there are two or more  with the same label?

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form>
  <label>Card Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" />
  <br />
  <label>ZIP</label>
  <input type="text" name="billingZip" id="billingZip" />
  <br />
    <label>Street</label>
    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" />
    <br />
    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
    <br />
    <label>ZIP</label>
    <input type="text" name="shippingZip" id="shippingZip" />
</form>
```

But autocomplete always fills the first ZIP field, not the second one; I want autocomplete to fill the second field.
I tried adding an `autoComplete` label to the second ZIP input, and `new-password` to the first one, but now, neither field is filled.

```
<form>
  <label>Card Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" />
  <br />
  <label>ZIP</label>
  <input type="text" name="billingZip" id="billingZip" autoComplete="new-password"/>
  <br />
    <label>Street</label>
    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" />
    <br />
    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
    <br />
    <label>ZIP</label>
    <input type="text" name="shippingZip" id="shippingZip" autoComplete="postal-code" />
</form>
```

Edit 1:
It also doesn't work when using fieldsets like this

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Card Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" />
    <br />
    <label>ZIP</label>
    <input type="text" name="billingZip" id="billingZip" />
  </fieldset>
  <br />

  <fieldset>
    <label>Street</label>
    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" />
    <br />
    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
    <br />
    <label>ZIP</label>
    <input type="text" name="shippingZip" id="shippingZip" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-meadow-wdwgrx?file=/src/App.js

EDIT:
I fixed this by using the `name`, and `autoComplete` fields in  and the `htmlFor` field in

https://codepen.io/Cesar-Vega-the-flexboxer/pen/abXYYGP

Comment: Hm, the browser shouldn't care about the label, since that's not the input field node, and doesn't need to be anywhere near it. However, on a `<label>` markup note: if your inputs have `id` attributes, mark your label as being "for that input" by using `<label for="id-of-the-input">...</label>`. One thing that _might_ help is to organize your form with fieldsets (especially since you have two sets of fields, one set for shipping, and one set for billing).

Comment: When you write "label" do you mean the text content of the `<label>` element or the value that the user writes into the `<input>` element? And maybe you could also explain what you would like to  achieve in the end.